# Export different lists to csv

Tags: vb.net, csv

at first, I have to say: I am completely new to Visual Basic Studio...

My problem is: I have different list objects of different types

```
List<Student> s
List<Teacher> t
List<Subject> su
```

and some more.

Each list has several attributes, mainly simple strings and int, some other complex type. For each class (Student..), I wrote a toString() method.

What I need: a simple method to write every list object to a csv file (alternatively, write it directly into a mysql table - but that has to wait..).
I found a simple method like this:

```
public void SaveToFile()
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("test.csv"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(mylist[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to make this method generic by taking the source list as a parameter, but this is not possible:

```
public void SaveToFile(List l)
```

because the type has to be declared.

What would be the simplest way? I am thinking either in a objectorientated way (finding a "superclass" for all different list types..) as well as searching for a simple component that does the job.

Any hints? (and sorry if my question is too simple...)

Thanks! Heiko

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code.  The first step is to find out what language you are programming in.  Tools for creating CSVs abound

Comment: Touché :-). As mentioned before, the "Visual Studio" thing is not my world. Your post pointed me towards C# instead of vb.net - now I understand why there were so few hits of my search.. Thank you, Plutonix!